# How to process notifications from NSNotificationCenter in QT application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, qt

Have a simple QT console app, with QCoreApplication.
Is it possible to process notifications from notification center in another thread? For example create a thread and connect loop of this thread to process notifications? Or extend QT application to send me this notifications?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of example in the source of Qt itself.(I did "git grep NSNotificationCenter" here.)

At least you could check the solution like following:
https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoaapplicationdelegate.mm

[L105-L109](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoaapplicationdelegate.mm#L105-L109):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(updateScreens:)
                   name:NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification
                 object:NSApp];
```

[L130](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoaapplicationdelegate.mm#L130):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```